# Break in console.log?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have an irksome problem in my node.js test code. Somewhere, something prints out an error message using console.log (i think). I am somewhat fastidious about clutter in my logs, so I trying to catch whatever it is. I am 100% sure that it's not in my code, it must be in some library we're using.

This brought me to an interesting question: is it possible to set a breakpoint in console.log? I'm working in WebStorm IDE and I'm running on node.js 4.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite `console.log` with a custom version that breaks into the debugger:

```
var _log = console.log.bind(console);

// es6
console.log = (...args) => {
  _log(...args);
  debugger;
}

// es5
console.log = function() {
  _log.apply(null, arguments);
  debugger;
}
```

Here's a one-liner if you'd like to copy/paste into a browser console for a drive test (verified in Chrome 51, Safari 9.1, and Firefox 46):

```
var _log = console.log.bind(console); console.log = function() { _log.apply(null, arguments); debugger; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log('Threw Exception: ' + err.stack);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but I wasn't looking for an uncaught exception. Only a console.log call.